# Powerbuilder 7 crashes while trying to insert OLE control

Tags: registry, ole, powerbuilder

I am trying to insert an OLE custom control to a dialog in Powerbuilder 7. When I choose the corresponding tab for 'Insert Control', the powerbuilder 7 application crashes. Upon my research on this topic, I found quite a few people who have experienced this behavior but none of their suggestions seems to work for me. One of the most relevant suggestion was to run process monitor and look for the last registry entry where PB7 crashes.

http://codeverge.com/sybase.powerbuilder.general/pb8-crashes-when-selecting-to-ins/1030907

I tried doing that and further looked into the OLE object viewer to look for anything unusual. The OLE object viewere crashed too when I selected OLE objects--> Bitmap objects.
I believe I do not understand the concept of registries too well to interpret the results and look for the appropriate solution.  I would really appreciate any help on this regard.
More Info: OS Windows7 Enterprise 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

Earlier versions of PB (10 and under) will abort if your system has a COM control that isn't installed correctly. It could be a COM control installer didn't set a registry setting it is supposed to. I would look for a utility that is designed to find and correct these sorts of issues.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Roland. I tried to unregister and re-register the COM controls. Is there a way to check if these were registered correctly? I used OLE/COM object viewer to look for some clues, but I have no idea what to look for.

Comment: This happened to me so long ago I don't remember how I fixed it. There is a built in Windows program scanreg that might fix it. I haven't tried it myself.